# Numbers as ID in web pages isnt working!

Tags: jquery, firefox

I was just wondering why my jquery event woudlnt be triggerd in FireFox when im using Numeric Values in my ID tags

Like `($"#2").live .....`

and `<div id='2' .....`

ive noticed that the events arent triggerd this way and only in FireFox. Any explanation is welcome.

Comment: Because numbers are not valid first-characters for the `id` or `class` attributes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, was this question answered to your satisfaction? Or did you have further problems?

Answer (score 4):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
>   [Citation: html 4 reference at the W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

So your `id` is not valid, as it starts with a numeric character.

Under [HTML 5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#the-id-attribute) however the `id` is only required to have:

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

Comment: I 2nd this post. idName-1, idName-2 et al. may be the approrpirate naming scheme. I would then use a regex to parse such a string.  such as this: 

//set regex
var re = /(^\w+-)(\d+)$/i;

//get attr broken into parts
var str = $(this).attr('id').match(re)[1], 
    id  = $(this).attr('id').match(re)[2];

Answer (score 2):

It isn't valid `HTML4` to have IDs that begin with a number.

You must start them with a letter.

Numeric IDs are allowed in `HTML5` though.

Answer (score 0):

ID values for html elements must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what `($"#2")` is doing.  If it's passing `#2` to a `querySelector` call, for example, that would fail because that's not a valid CSS selector.

I suspect you're using some sort of library that does something like that; it might work in other browsers due to bugs in their CSS selector parsers or due to the library doing browser-sniffing and not running the same code in those other browsers.